# FileSystem API & Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've got some troubles with my new ChromeApp.

So.. I've started using JavaScript FileSystem API, so i
use it to create mp3 files (my app is a html5 player).

The FileEntry object from the FileSystem API gives the `toURL()` method
for files which are stored in filesystem. In the ChormeApps this method
returns something like this:

```
filesystem:chrome-extension://mhldgbaidgpagmimniipggmajbodaeco/persistent/cbd416046ae7a567d4629fc38ac80864.mp3
```

But when i trying to use this url in `<audio>` tag as value for `src` attribute
i getting this error:

```
Refused to load media from 'filesystem:chrome-extension://mhldgbaidgpagmimniipggmajbodaeco/persistent/cbd416046ae7a567d4629fc38ac80864.mp3' because of Content-Security-Policy.
```

So i tried to use clear name with relative path

```
<audio src="cbd416046ae7a567d4629fc38ac80864.mp3" />
```

and with Chrome App root path

```
<audio src="chrome-extension://mhldgbaidgpagmimniipggmajbodaeco/cbd416046ae7a567d4629fc38ac80864.mp3"/>
```

and with "persistent" folder

```
<audio src="chrome-extension://mhldgbaidgpagmimniipggmajbodaeco/persistent/cbd416046ae7a567d4629fc38ac80864.mp3"/>
```

In last 3 cases i've got 404 error.
So, how can i enable loading media from filesystem? Something in the manifest in the  `content_security_policy` or maybe in the `permissions`? Or there is some magical path to use?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

**Update:**
I using `content_security_policy` directive:

```
default-src 'none'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src 'self' http://*.userapi.com; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src 'self' http://*.userapi.com http://vk.com http://last.fm http://ws.audioscrobbler.com; media-src 'self';
```

But `media-src 'self'` doesn't brought needed results. I still gettin' error "Refused load media".

**Update 2:**
I've found an ugly hack to do what i want: `media-src: 'self' *` does the job. But if you have some ideas on how to solve this problem i'll be really glad to see them.

**Update 3:**
Problem solved. Thanks to [Mihai Parparita](https://stackoverflow.com/users/343108/mihai-parparita) for his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use a `media-src 'self' filesystem:` CSP directive in order to allow filesystem: URLs (`'self'` only includes URLs directly in your extension, not wrapped `filesystem:` ones).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a "content_security_policy" string in your manifest.

If not, are you are using manifest_version : 2, then the "content_security_policy" is set to

> "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self';"

See Manifest version 2 [documentation](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifestVersion.html)

You might need to add the media source to the CSP string.

> media-src : 'self'

Content security policies are explained at [MDN here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Security/CSP/CSP_policy_directives).

Comment: Thanks for answe. I using manifest version 1 and have this CSP string: `"content_security_policy": "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' http://*.userapi.com http://vk.com http://last.fm http://ws.audioscrobbler.com;"`. Maybe i really need to use 2 version.. I'll try, thanks.

Comment: There's the trouble with manifest version 2 because of `unsafe-eval` options which doesn't work with this version of manifest ([Bug 4201](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4201&can=5&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal)). And `media-src 'self'` doesn't work in first version of manifest.